# how to Get&Put xively data with android 2.3.6

Tags: android, xively

Is this code will work in Android, I am using xively and  xively's requirements are:

```
X-ApiKey            API_KEY_HERE
User-Agent          Device Agent
Content-Length      length
Host                api.xively.com
Content-Encoding    utf-8,gzip
```

Please, could you help me to enable the gzip compression format

```
public String httpGet(String s) {
String url = s;
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // create new httpClient
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); // create new httpGet object

try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); // execute httpGet
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        // System.out.println(statusLine);
        body.append(statusLine + "\n");
        HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
        String entity = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        body.append(entity);
    } else {
        body.append(statusLine + "\n");
        // System.out.println(statusLine);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpGet.releaseConnection(); // stop connection
}
return body.toString(); // return the String
}
```

Comment: Hey user3145687,if you are using any API(X-ApiKey API_KEY_HERE). Dont Call it in android Please create a Restful service ,. an Restful service Can be created for exiting Web site also, So create a Restful webservice, and dont give the Key in android Side if You give any body can easily decode that and Your valuable key will be Miss used,. so use that key on server side and

Comment: Thank you very much user3124880,

Comment: Xively's parameters are defined in the site also. How to use REST in android to Get&Put data to&from xively???

Answer (score 0):

Xively does not require using the gzip format, you can use it, but it is not required. Your problem here probably that you are not setting the API key in the header in your actual code. That should be the only header you need to specify. HttpClient should take care of the rest.